# Parent process working until child processes finish

Tags: c, fork, ipc, wait

A **parent** process **D** creates *3* **child** processes , **A/B/C** , with fork.

The parent process shall communicate with child processes , until all child processes finish  .

Is there any simple way to make parent work with children and make him terminate when children do , so ?

```
Parent Process                                  Child Process
--------------                                  --------------
int main(){                                     int main(){
  // create children ... 
  while( all children are alive ){               for(sometime){
      // ipc with children                         // ipc with parent
   }                                              }

   return 0;                                      return 0;
}                                               }
```

Comment: Yes, you'd use `wait` (and possibly a `SIGCHLD` handler).

Comment: You can do it using wait and waitpid.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any simple way to make parent work with children and make him terminate when children do , so ?* yes it's very simple, all you need to do is use `fork()` to create the child process, and each child need to send their status to parent by calling `exit()`  and in parent use `waitpid()` or [wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) such that parent process should wait for all child i.e when there is no child exists `waitpid()` returns `-1`.

For example below is the sample child parent code.

```
int a[3]; //to store pid's of children
int main(void) {
        if( (a[0]=fork()) == 0) { /* 1st child */
                int randNo;
                srand(getpid());
                randNo=rand()%10+1;
                printf("1st_child sleep for %d sec\n",randNo);
                sleep(randNo);
                exit(1); /* sending the exit status to parent */
        }
        else {
                if( (a[1]=fork()) == 0) { /* 1nd child */
                        int randNo;
                        srand(getpid());
                        randNo=rand()%10+1;
                        printf("2nd_child sleep for %d sec\n",randNo);
                        sleep(randNo);
                        exit(2);
                }
                else {
                        if( (a[3]=fork()) == 0) { /*1rd child */
                                int randNo;
                                srand(getpid());
                                randNo=rand()%10+1;
                                printf("3rd_child sleep for %d sec\n",randNo);
                                sleep(randNo);
                                exit(3);
                        }
                        else { /* common parent for all 3 child */
                                int status; //exit status of child
                                //signal(SIGCHLD,my_isr);
                                while(wait(&status) != -1) { /* when there is no child, wait() returns -1 */
                                        if( status>>8 == 1 ) { /* if 1st child status received */
                                                a[0] = 0;
                                                printf("child_1 removed from zombie \n");
                                        }
                                        else if( status>>8 == 2) {
                                                a[1] = 0;
                                                printf("child_2 removed from zombie \n");
                                        }
                                        else if( status>>8 == 3) {
                                                a[2] = 0;
                                                printf("child_3 removed from zombie \n");
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Also you can set one `signal handler` as when child completes it sends `SIGCHLD` to parent, hence upon receiving this signal parent understood that child's completed & it needs to free resources occupied by parents.